# PHP - string to money conversion

Tags: php, currency

I'm trying to convert a string into money format using [this function](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php), and trying to create something like this :

```
350000000

to

350.000.000,00
```

All my attempts failed so far, being this the last one :

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'pt_PT.UTF-8@euro');
echo money_format('%.2n', $preco);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: What's wrong with money_format?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the output of your `money_format` call.

Comment: Does `'echo \`locale -a\`;'` give you any decent locales you want to use?

Comment: B.t.w: as you as you have a decent locale your desired format is most likely `"%!n"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) like this:

```
$number = 350000000;
$money_number = number_format($number,2,',','.');
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to [compile locale definition files](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_localedef.htm) for Portuguese, it should go something like:

```
localedef -ci pt_PT -f utf-8 pt_PT
```